# Crealytics Spark Excel Package import issues

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-poi, spark-excel

I am trying to process Excel files using Spark. I have created a session and added the dependent jar and package in configuration.

Spark Version = 3.1.1
Scala version = 2.12

I have added this jar = "spark-excel_2.12-3.1.1_0.18.7".

But still I am getting this error while trying to read an excel file.

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o40.load.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookProvider
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:38)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:29)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:24)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:354)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:326)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:308)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:308)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:240)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookProvider
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 20 more
```

I tried adding

poi-5.2.3.jar
poi-ooxml-5.2.3.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.2.jar

but still getting the same error.

What could be the issue here. as I have tried to be careful about spark version etc.

Regards